# Return index of first array change

Tags: javascript

Given the array `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`, how do I return the index of the first change (index 2 in this case, where it changed from `0` to `1`).

Another example, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]` should return `5`.

Comment: loop through, compare elements, get index of items that are not equal.

Comment: You could use a for loop and variable which contains the first element and then you check if the current element is different from the first.

Comment: There are lots of ways this can be done. Please show what you have tried. This isn't a free code writing service

Answer (score 4):

Use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2];

var b = a.findIndex(v => a[0] !== v);

console.log(b);
```

Note that findIndex is not supported by IE, but you can use the polyfill found at the documentation page I linked to.

Comment: that first example uses two scans of the array when only one is necessary.

Comment: Changed the answer @Alnitak, I first had the illusion that `find` is supported by more browser versions than `findIndex`, but both are supported by the same versions...

Comment: Good - the first example was pretty poor, IMHO.  Not only did it scan twice, but in a generic use case it would have had odd behaviour if any of the values was `undefined`.

Comment: NB: `x => { return y }` can just be written as `x => y`

Comment: True too. @Alnitak

Comment: Also, please use `!==` instead of the loose `!=` operator!

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will solve

```
var givenArray = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2];

    function result(arr) {
        var PreValue = undefined;
        for(var i in arr){
            if(PreValue != undefined && PreValue != arr[i]) {
                return i;
            }
            PreValue = arr[i];
        }
    }

    console.log(result(givenArray));
```